# LESS: associative array in LOOP

Tags: for-loop, less, mixins, less-mixins

I need to add an icon to a page, depending by its content. In other words, if a page contain an image, a gallery, a video... I'll add an icon indicating its nature.

To do this, I add CSS class to `body` tag and use *descendant selector* to add icons in the proper position.

Obviously this task results in a lot of repeating code in CSS, so I would like to generate it with a [LESS Loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature).

Here my actual attempt (*icons are icon-fonts*):

```
@icons:"\e926", "\e90e", "\e914";

.icons-loop(@i; @ico) when (@i <= length(@ico)) {

  @page-type:extract(@ico, @i);

  .page-type_@{page-type}
  {
      #icon_container:before
      {
        content: extract(@icons, @i);
      }
  }

  .icons-loop((@i + 1), @ico);
}

.icons(@ico...) {
  .icons-loop(1, @ico);
}

.icons(image, gallery, video);
```

I wrote this, taking inspiration from other similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151864/less-loop-using-data-stored-in-an-array-or-something-similar).

It works, but I admit that is not yet what I really would like, for two reasons:

- I think that current need of a variable `@icons` to declare icon entities, and a mixins `.icons` to declare different page-type is not so intuitive, due to eterogeneous type. It should be better to be able to use LESS variable in both declarations, for coherency
- Could be surely better to write a sort of **associative array**, in which I could declare in the same place, correspondance between page-type and relative icon. Something like this:

`@page-type: image, "\e926"; gallery, "\e90e"; video, "\e914";`

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658087

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly achieve the associative array behavior in Less as shown below as Less can split and [extract values both based on comma as well as space](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract).

In this case we separate multiple page-icon combinations by a comma and then within each page-icon combo, the page type and icon value are separated by space.

```css
@page-icon-list: image "\e926", gallery "\e90e", video "\e914"; //the 2D array

.loop(@index) when (@index > 0){
    @page-icon: extract(@page-icon-list, @index); //extract based on comma separator each page-icon combo
    @page-type: extract(@page-icon,1); //first part of the extracted value is the page type
    @icon: extract(@page-icon,2); //second part is the icon
    .page-type_@{page-type}{
      #icon_container:before
      {
        content: @icon;
      }        
    }
    .loop(@index - 1);
}
.loop(length(@page-icon-list)); //pass the length as counter (split based on comma)
```

Comment: first version you wrote was correct but now I have an error on "@page-icon undefined". (I tried with less2css.org) :-)

Comment: Sorry, I changed the variable and forgot to modify in all places. Please check now :)