# Generate CSS classes from a list of values in LESS

Tags: less, less-mixins

I have a LESS loop that generates different CSS (incremental) classes extracting color values from a list.

My current **LESS** code is the following:

```css
.generate-detached(#f00, #0f0, #00f);

.generate-detached(@colors...) 
{
    .generate-detached-loop(1, @colors);
}

.generate-detached-loop(@i; @colors) when (@i <= length(@colors)) {
    @color: extract(@colors, @i);

    .detached-@{i} 
    {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px @color;

        > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before
        {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px @color;
        }
    }

    .generate-detached-loop((@i + 1), @colors);
}
```

The resulting **CSS** code is:

```css
.detached-1 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px #f00;
}
.detached-1 > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px #f00;
}
.detached-2 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px #0f0;
}
.detached-2 > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px #0f0;
}
.detached-3 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px #00f;
}
.detached-3 > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px #00f;
}
```

Maybe I'm using old LESS constructs and actually exist some new techniques or in general... have you any idea to improve solution?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?   Are you just asking if this is a good solution?

Comment: I know that is running correctly, but it's a quite verbose and a little unreadable. I thought that maybe there could be some new features in last version of LESS that could let to achieve same results with a more compact code or more intuitive (an example could be new `if()` statement instead of old `when()` guards)

Comment: *an example could be new if() statement instead of old when() guards* - If you mean the `if` function in Less v3 is not a replacement for `when` guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more about *your* knowledge and understanding of existing language features rather than about language features themselves.

I.e. even in Less v2 (you're probably using) it's difficult to justify the existence of 4 extra lines of the `.generate-detached(@colors...)` mixin you have there.

E.g. why not:

```css
@detached-colors: #f00 #0f0 #00f;

.detached-loop(@i: length(@detached-colors)) when (@i > 0) {
    .detached-loop(@i - 1);
    .detached-@{i} {
        @c: extract(@detached-colors, @i);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px @c;
        > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px @c;
        }
    }
} .detached-loop;
```

**Or**:

```css
.make-detached(#f00 #0f0 #00f);
.make-detached(@colors, @i: length(@colors)) when (@i > 0) {
    .make-detached(@colors, @i - 1);
    .detached-@{i} {
        @c: extract(@colors, @i);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px @c;
        > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px @c;
        }
    }
}
```

?

---

Less v3 has `each` function:

```css
each(#f00 #0f0 #00f, {
    .detached-@{index} {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px @value;
        > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px @value;
        }
    }
});
```

---

But the similar thing exists for Less v2 as a plugin:

```css
.for-each(@c, @i in @l: #f00 #0f0 #00f) {
    .detached-@{i} {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 2px @c;
        > .toolbar > .drag-controls_container > .drag-control:before {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px @c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I started from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151864/less-loop-using-data-stored-in-an-array-or-something-similar](this similar question solution) to develop this code. Anyway, your first solution runs correctly but values are stored in a map? The second one has some errors because it prints also "colors" or "extract(colors)" (at least trying with [http://lesscss.org/less-preview/](less-preview)). The v3 version is very nice and compact, the only thing is that is not possible to separate loop definition from values declaration

Comment: I saw that is possible to change a little v3 each version declaring `@detached-colors:#f00 #0f0 #00f;` and then replace each definition with `each(@detached-colors, {` really not bad. Just a remaining question, how does it works definition of different values of `@detached-colors:#f00 #0f0 #00f;` ? I tried also to remove spaces and it continues to work, so it's not the presence of spaces that separate values... I don't understand what kind of construct it is and I am unable to find documentation about it in official one

Comment: As for `@detached-colors:#f00 #0f0 #00f;` - I intentionally did not used a variable (except the example #2) just because *you* did not in your snippet (thus `.generate-detached(#f00, #0f0, #00f);` -> `each(#f00 #0f0 #00f ...`).

Comment: `#f00 #0f0 #00f` -well, it *is* [space separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011089) of values (in general there's no critical difference between comma and space lists (not counting context depended conventions like func arg list and so on)). *I tried also to remove spaces and it continues to work* - don't rely on that - in this particular case spaces can be ommited only because `#` itself is a non-ambiguous separator (so the spaces are assumed automatically like in a compressed CSS) - but normally the space must be there (well, assuming you're about writing a human-readable code).